# Pandas resampling with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame containing information about stores. It looks like the following:

`date      | store_id |   x
2019-01-01|    1     |   5
2019-01-01|    2     |   1
2019-01-05|    1     |   3
...`

The multi-index is [`date`,`store_id`]. Note that the dates are not unique. 
I want to resample the data at an hourly level, but only for the days in the `date` column i.e. I don't want to fill in every hour in between. Furthermore, I want to fill in the value of x for every hour that is created. So the desired result for the above example would be

`date               | store_id |   x
2019-01-01 00:00:00|    1     |   5
2019-01-01 01:00:00|    1     |   5
2019-01-01 02:00:00|    1     |   5
...
2019-01-01 23:00:00|    1     |   5
2019-01-01 00:00:00|    2     |   1
2019-01-01 01:00:00|    2     |   1
2019-01-01 02:00:00|    2     |   1
...
2019-01-01 23:00:00|    2     |   1
2019-01-05 00:00:00|    1     |   3
2019-01-05 01:00:00|    1     |   3
2019-01-05 02:00:00|    1     |   3
...
2019-01-05 23:00:00|    1     |   3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the following "replication" function:

```
def repl(row):
    return pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start=row.date,
        periods=24, freq='H'),'store_id': row.store_id, 'x': row.x})
```

It "replicates" the source row (parameter), returning a sequence of rows
with the given *date*, for consecutive hours.

Then:

- reset the index, to have all columns as "normal" columns,
- apply this function (to each row),
- convert the resulting *Series* of DataFrames into a list (of DataFrames),
- concatenate the result.

The code to do it is:

```
pd.concat(df.reset_index().apply(repl, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```